# Automatic State mutation in ReactJS - Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using State in React and I have placed an `onChange` listener on an input component which calls `nameChangeHandler`, and I am running into a strange mutation issue.

Here is my state object:

```
state = {
    persons: [
      { id: '363724', name: 'Person1', age: 28, job: 'React Developer' },
      { id: '724324', name: 'Person2', age: 49, job: 'General Manager' },
      { id: '753424', name: 'Person3', age: 25, job: 'ITSM Consultant' }
    ]
};
```

And then the below code `this.state.person` logs updated state with an extra character(which I type in), even though I am not using setState anywhere and neither I am mutating the state directly.

```
nameChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p => p.id === id);
    const newPersons = [...this.state.persons];
    
    newPersons[personIndex].name = event.target.value;
  
    console.log(newPersons);
    console.log(this.state.persons);
    //this.setState({});
};
```

Here is a screenshot of dev console.

[automatic mutation of state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hlb0.png)

Can someone help?

Comment: Yes you are. `newPersons[personIndex].name = event.target.value;`. Spread syntax IS NOT deep! It does not copy your deeply nested object values!

Comment: Hey, Thanks! Do we have any alternative to spread in ES6 to create a deep clone? Because this would require to clone the objects too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es6 spread syntax does shallow copy not deep copy.So when you are trying to create new nested objects from existing one you have to use deep copy methods.

For deep-copying of nested objects you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`

Here you have an array of objects so what you can do is:

```
let newPersons = this.state.persons.map(person => {return {...person}})
```